# rails-perftest `require': cannot load such file -- test_helper (LoadError)

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

I try execute benchmark test with perftest, but rake crashes with error message  `require': cannot load such file -- test_helper (LoadError)`

The complete return error message with trace ( `bundle exec rake test:benchmark --trace` ) is:

```
/home/app/tracker/test/performance/homepage_test.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- test_helper (LoadError)
from /home/app/tracker/test/performance/homepage_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib" "/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/performance/**/*_test.rb" ]
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:108:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84:in `ruby'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `ruby'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:58:in `verbose'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb:100:in `block in define'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:benchmark
```

Ruby Version

> 2.1.4 (set by /home/user/.rbenv/version)

Rails Version

> 4.0.11

github gem

https://github.com/rails/rails-perftest

Comment: were you ever able to find a fix for this?

Comment: No, I did not find any solution :(

Comment: Here is what worked for me. In my case, I was missing the actual `test_helper` file which gets generated by default with every rails app (you can rails g a dummy app and copy it from there), and the `minitest` gem.

Comment: yes, but i use rspec. If it include this file, i have problems with rspec.

Comment: Im also using Rspec, and also expected installing Minitest to cause problems with my MVC test suite. However, all my tests are running fine.

Comment: Perfect. this works for me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try include

require 'test_helper'

on top of your test..

Comment: Thanks, but answer duplicate. Please see you @Dimitry_N in comments.